# Need help verifying proof for showing that a vector can be expressed as a linear combination in more than one way

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am struggling to prove the following question regarding linear combinations:

I am given that that $u = (1,2,3)$, $v = (0,1,2)$ and $w = (3,1,-1)$ are vectors in $R^3$.

The question is asking me to show that a vector $x = (8, 5, 2)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $u$, $v$ and $w$ in more than one way.

I am not sure if the logic in my proof is correct:

Suppose that $x(1,2,3)+y(0,1,2)+z(3,1,-1)=(8,5,2)$ where $x,y,$ and $z$ are scalars.

By scalar multiplication and vector addition, we have the following:

$(x+3z,2x+y+z,3x+2y-z)=(8,5,2)$

We can now set up a system of equations, where
$x+3z=8$
$2x+y+z=5$
$3x+2y-z=2$

Solving the system of equations using $x=8-3z$, we get

$2x+y+z=5$

$2(8-3z)+y+z=5$

$16-6z+y+z=5$

$y=5z-11$

This is where I'm stuck. For the other questions where I had prove that a vector is a linear combination, I typically ended up with real number solutions when solving the system of equations. However, for this system of equations, there does not appear to be a "unique" solution.

Would it be correct to assume that since there are multiple solutions for $x,y,$ and $z$, that $x$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $u$, $v$, $w$ in more than one way? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: Are you aware of solving system of linear equations? Consistent, inconsistent?

Comment: You are using $x$ for $(8,5,2)$ and also for the coefficient of $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding. (Also, chances are this is a duplicate.)